# Detect stop sharing event in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am developing some webrtc stuff. A problem I am having is firefox users starting a session and then using the "stop sharing" dialog built into firefox to end the session. It doesn't really end the session though, it just kills audio/video. Is there an event or something that gets fired when users stop sharing? And where would I find such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

stream.onended should be called but there is an open bug on it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1045810

I think the workaround described there is also currently broken but I haven't checked recently.